# Cypher query to calculate cosine score between two neo4j nodes of the same label

Tags: neo4j, cypher, cosine-similarity

I am trying to write a Cypher query for a specific use case and I am unable to come up with one.

I have a neo4j database. I have populated it with nodes and relationships in the following fashion.
(Context: This database represent queries and products for an e-commerce website)

Each node has one of the following two labels

1. Query
2. Product

A relationship only exists from a Query node to a Product node (indicating a click on that product after a user enters the query). The edge has a score indicating the total number of clicks.

I want to define a score which measures the overlap between any two query nodes. So for each query node I define a vector with total number of components equal to total number of products. Each component is equal to the score on the edge between the query and that product.

I now want to calculate the cosine of the angle between these two vectors. But I am unable to write a single cypher query which returns the cosine score for each query, query' pair.

The best I could come up with is this query

```
MATCH (q1:Query {search_term:'sunglasses'})-[e1:INTERACTION
{event_type:'CLICK'}]->(p:Product)<-[e2:INTERACTION 
{event_type:'CLICK'}]-(q2:Query) 
WITH q1, q2, sqrt(sum(e1.score * e1.score)) as sq1, sqrt(sum(e2.score * 
e2.score)) as sq2, sum(e1.score * e2.score) as overlap_score
RETURN q1, q2, overlap_score/(sq1 * sq2) as cosine
ORDER BY cosine DESC
```

But this query does not calculate the cosine of the angle between vectors because while calculating the length of each of the vectors (sq1 and sq2 in the above query), it ignores those components where the second query has a 0 component.

I know this question took some describing, but I haven't been able to find a solution for this. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Do you know `OPTIONAL MATCH` ? MATCH (q1:Query {search_term:'sunglasses'})-[e1:INTERACTION
{event_type:'CLICK'}]->(p:Product) OPTIONAL MATCH (p)<-[e2:INTERACTION 
{event_type:'CLICK'}]-(q2:Query)

Comment: Optional match will make sure we get all edges coming out of q1. But the query will miss those edges which are coming out of q2 to a product p' such that there is no edge from q1 to that product p'. OPTIONAL MATCH unfortunately does not help here

Answer (score 1):

If you check [this graphgist](https://neo4j.com/graphgist/a7c915c8-a3d6-43b9-8127-1836fecc6e2f), we can easily steal and modify the query that you are looking for.

Your query would look something like:

```
MATCH (p1:Query {search_term:'sunglasses'})-[x:INTERACTION
{event_type:'CLICK'}]->(p:Product)<-[y:INTERACTION 
{event_type:'CLICK'}]-(p2:Query) 

WITH  SUM(x.score * y.score) AS xyDotProduct,
      SQRT(REDUCE(xDot = 0.0, a IN COLLECT(x.score) | xDot + a^2)) AS xLength,
      SQRT(REDUCE(yDot = 0.0, b IN COLLECT(y.score) | yDot + b^2)) AS yLength,
      p1, p2
MERGE (p1)-[s:SIMILARITY]-(p2)
SET   s.similarity = xyDotProduct / (xLength * yLength)
```

Check out also [APOC's documentation on cosine similarity](https://github.com/neo4j-contrib/neo4j-apoc-procedures/blob/3.2/docs/similarity.adoc)